# How can we select and update a table in laravel 5.4 using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am working in laravel 5.4 and trying to select few data from table and update a field of table. I followed below script. I am not sure Is this correct method or not. Please correct me.

```
$bookings   = Booking::where('is_delete', 0)
            ->where('status', '1')
            ->where('payment_status', '1')
            ->get();

foreach($bookings as $booking) {
    $booking->status = '3';
    $booking->save();
}
```

Comment: You could always hit [the manual or a tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/update-multiple-records-using-eloquent) If you were that way inclined

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$bookings   = Booking::where('is_delete', 0)
                ->where('status', '1')
                ->where('payment_status', '1')
                ->get();

foreach($bookings as $booking) 
{
    Booking::where('id',$booking->id)->update(['status'=>'3']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply update like

```
Booking::where('is_delete', 0)->where('status', '1')->where('payment_status', '1')->update(['status'=>'3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

More Simple Update Coding...

```
Booking::where([['is_delete', '=', 0], ['status', '=', '1'], ['payment_status', '=', '1']])->update(['status' => '3']);
```